# I need an update of this Class Code for myBBIntegrator

Tags: mybb

I am have an error from myBBIntegrator

thrown in /home/fxmentorcom/public_html/index.php on line 13
[21-Dec-2020 12:52:35 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; MyBBIntegrator has a deprecated constructor in /home/fxmentorcom/public_html/class.MyBBIntegrator.php on line 31

Answer (score 0):

You should try using latest version of that class

https://github.com/olada/MyBBIntegrator/